# Android open gl es 2.0 drawing text

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Anyone who can tell which of these methods to render text in opengl es 2.0 is faster:decoding an image(32x27) png into a bitmap ,or drawing text with canvas to a bitmap??Both bitmaps are use to texture.

Answer (score 0):

Decoding PNGs will always be slow because it is done in software and there are serious complications with converting images with alpha from the Android Bitmap class to an OpenGL texture.  There is an excellent solution already available in the PowerVR [SDK](http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/) named Print3D.  See the example named 06_IntroducingPrint3D.